# JSON WP REST API getting featured image by Taxonomy Terms

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I'm trying to get a featured-image from my custom `taxonomy-*projects* term-*elfla*.`

I managed to get a image from the posts with this code what i found [here](https://1fix.io/blog/2015/09/29/wp-api-v2-angularjs-theme/) but I don't understand how to do it with taxonomy terms.

At this point I do not understand how to get the featured image source and whether the 'GET' request url is correct.

JS:

```js
var portfolioPostsBtn = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-btn");
var portfolioPostsContainer = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container");

if (portfolioPostsBtn) {
  portfolioPostsBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET','http://localhost/test/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter=projects&filter=elfla&_embed'); 
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
      if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        createHTML(data);
        portfolioPostsBtn.remove();
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
      }
    };
    ourRequest.onerror = function() {
      console.log("Connection error");
    };

    ourRequest.send();
  });
}

function createHTML(postsData) {
  var ourHTMLString = '';
  for (i = 0; i < postsData.length; i++) {

   ourHTMLString += '<img src="'+postsData[i].featured_image_thumbnail_url+ '" alt="img">';

  }
  portfolioPostsContainer.innerHTML = ourHTMLString;




  
}
```

***Functions.php***

```
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
$_data = $data->data;
$thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $post->ID , 'thumbnlai' false );
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id );
$_data['featured_image_thumbnail_url'] = $thumbnail[0];
$data->data = $_data;
return $data;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function.

```
**function custom_api_get_all_posts() {
register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', '/all-posts', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'custom_api_get_all_posts_callback'
)); } 
function custom_api_get_all_posts_callback( $request ) {
// Initialize the array that will receive the posts' data. 
$posts_data = array();
// Receive and set the page parameter from the $request for pagination purposes
$paged = $request->get_param( 'page' );
$paged = ( isset( $paged ) || ! ( empty( $paged ) ) ) ? $paged : 1; 
// Get the posts using the 'post' and 'news' post types
$posts = get_posts( array(
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 1000,            
        'post_type' => array('post') // This is the line that allows to fetch multiple post types. 
    )
); 
// Loop through the posts and push the desired data to the array we've initialized earlier in the form of an object
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    $id = $post->ID; 
    $post_thumbnail = ( has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ) ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id ) : null;

    $posts_data[] = (object) array( 
        'id' => $id, 
        'slug' => $post->post_name, 
        'type' => $post->post_type,
        'title' => $post->post_title,
        "content" => apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content),
        'featured_img_src' => $post_thumbnail
    );
}                  
return $posts_data; }
```

use this link http://yourdomin.com/wp-json/custom/v1/all-posts.
I think it will work for you

Comment: can you explain how to use it with my javascript file?